# (SQL) Set Multiple Data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to set multiple date data, example data

```
+--+-------------------+
|ID|date               |
+--+-------------------+
|1 |2017-05-01 00:00:01|
|2 |2017-05-01 00:00:01|
|3 |2017-05-01 00:00:01|
|4 |2017-05-01 00:00:01|
|5 |2017-05-01 00:00:01|
|6 |2017-05-01 00:00:01|
+--+-------------------+
```

I want to set them to 2017-05-01 until 2017-05-06, but i dont know the query to set them, is there anyone know how to do it? thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

If that is all the content of the table you want to use an *UPDATE* statement without filters using the *ID* to increase the *DATE* value by days:

```
UPDATE tbl
   SET date = date_add(date, INTERVAL (id - 1) DAY)
```